# Keycloak - Can you add custom claims to client credentials?

Tags: jwt, single-sign-on, keycloak, minio

I'm using keycloak to get access tokens but I need those jwt tokens to have a 'policy' attribute/claim that [MinIO](https://min.io/) requires.

Now, I can get those by calling the token endpoint with grant_type =  password, plus username and pass.

I know that that policy attribute is mapped from the user, but, is there any possibility that I could get client creds (grant_type =  client_credentials) including that attribute? or any other type of grant?

Comment: I can see only the roles items in the "Mapper Type" of "Create Protocol Mapper" dropbox menu not policy items. Any reason to use policy-based authorization instead of role-based AuthZ?

Answer (score 3):

you can add Mapper to the client

```
Mapper Type: "hardcoded claim"

Token Claim Name: <token body key>, in your case is 'policy'

Claim value : <the value>
```

Comment: Wont this be included in user credentials grant type requests also?

Answer (score 0):

As Client Mappers are applicable to any token issued to this client, it should be avoided as much as possible in case of specific scenarios.

- Define "scope" and add "hard code mapper" with custom claims.
- Add this scope to client -> client scope -> optional scopes
- Pass this scope while requesting client credentials